# OOPS concepts Call function of Parent class not Child

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have a Parent class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Parent {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public void process(){
        System.out.println("parent");
        this.checkFunction();
    }

    protected void checkFunction(){
        System.out.println("parentC");
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public void init(){
        (map).put("parent","b");

    }
}
```

Now, as expected I have a child class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Child extends Parent {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public void checkFunction(){
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println("ChildC");

    }

    public void process(){
        super.process();
        System.out.println("Child");

    }

    public void init(){

        super.init();
        (map).put("child","b");

    }
}
```

To test what I want, I have a main class.

```
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Child a = new Child();
        a.init();
        a.process();
        Parent p = a;
        p.checkFunction();
    }

}
```

When I call a.process(), I assume it should call child.process() which will in return call super.process(). So far so good. In Parent's process(), it should call checkFunction().

Now, as per my understanding it should call checkFunction() of Parent class. Why is it calling Child's checkFunction()?

My output is something like this

```
parent
{child=b}
ChildC
Child
{child=b}
ChildC
```

I expect it to be

```
parent
parentC
{parent=b}
Child
{child=b}
ChildC
```

Comment: Calling `Child.checkFunction` is correct. This is the nature of Java's dynamic polymorphism. The target object of the invocation of `checkFunction` is an instance of `Child`, so its implementation of `checkFunction` will be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have overridden checkFunction in the child class. therefore an instance of child will call the child checkFunction even if the call is from parent class.

If you want to call the parents checkfunction from an instance of the child you need to call super.checkFunction() in the child class. The super keyword essentially "moves up" the inheritance chain.

A detailed description of the super keyword can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ricick. I still can't believe this is right. This changes everything for me. Anyways, how would I call the parent's checkFunction() from parent's class. By overriding, I understand I call the child's function not parent's but what does parent know about child's function when the call is made from parent. Kindly comment!

Comment: Essentially you can't. If you want to make sure a parent method is called in a subclass, don't override it. By overriding you are explicitly  saying "I don't want to use the parent method".

Comment: just to confirm the data access in the parent function would be that of parent only and not the child. (just like in the question above)